# Is there an idiomatic way to splice a list or vector into a function as arguments?

Tags: r

```
v <- runif(100, 0, 10)
seq(???(round(range(v))), length.out=5)
```

Is there a convenience function ??? or some other way to do this with minimal keystrokes---especially when working interactively.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for `do.call`

```
do.call(seq,c(round(range(v)),list(length.out=5)))
```

You need to use `c(...,list(OtherArgs))` to combine all of the arguments into a single list.

But if I wanted to do this with minimal keystrokes when working interactively I would probably just do it the "hard" way:

```
rv <- round(range(v))
seq(rv[1],rv[2],length.out=5)
```

(56 vs 51 keystrokes, but fewer nested parentheses to keep track of, and two short commands are probably easier than one long one)

Comment: thanks for the answer and I fixed the typo (I was trying to simplify what I was actually doing so messed that up)